# Como hago para que el While vacie la info del valor que tomo de la variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

El While loopea bien, deberia tomar todas los datos de @string_var despues de una coma, y el While por si solo da 2 loops, pero en el segundo loop, toma la variable 206029 y no carga datos, solo me refleja la primer variable, aunque agrege 5 datos divididos por coma, el while solo me refleja el primero.

no se que pueda ser, jamas me habia pasado con un while

El resultado de este query es la tabla temp_table_2 y la llena solo con la info que tenga el primer dato de la variable @string_var los demas los toma, pero no vacia info en las tablas del subwhile

```
DECLARE @string_var VARCHAR (100) = '198714,206029'
DECLARE @countloop     INT = 0
DECLARE @RowLoop       INT
DECLARE @monitor_ident INT
DECLARE @date_start    INT
DECLARE @date_end      INT
DECLARE @SQL           NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @query         VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @cnt           INT = 1
DECLARE @column        VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @error         VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @detail        VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @Date         DATE
SET @Date = GETDATE ()

CREATE TABLE Temp_table_2
(
    monitor_ident INT,
    monitor_date DATE,
    emp_monitor_ident INT,
    employee_ident INT,
    Column_name VARCHAR(1000),
    Column_value VARCHAR(1000)
)

SELECT 
    VALUE 
INTO #StringMB
FROM fn_pivotParametersINT (@string_var,',')

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value) AS 'ROWnum_for',
    VALUE
INTO #StringWhile
FROM #StringMB
SET @countloop = 1

WHILE @countloop <= (SELECT COUNT(ROWnum_for) FROM #StringWhile)
BEGIN
    SET @RowLoop  = (SELECT VALUE FROM #StringWhile WHERE ROWnum_for = @countloop)
    SET @monitor_ident = @RowLoop
SET @query = 'SELECT * 
INTO Temp_Table_1
FROM ##get_info_'+CAST(@monitor_ident AS VARCHAR)+' WITH (NOLOCK)'
EXEC(@query) 

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY c.NAME
    ) AS ROW_NUM,
    c.NAME AS Field_Name
INTO #columns
FROM SYS.COLUMNS c WITH(NOLOCK) 
     INNER JOIN SYS.OBJECTS o WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
     LEFT JOIN  SYS.TYPES t WITH (NOLOCK) ON t.user_type_id  = c.user_type_id 
WHERE  o.NAME = 'Temp_table_1'
ORDER BY o.NAME, c.NAME

/*=========================UNPIVOT THE CURRENT DATA INTO THE TEMPORAL TABLE*/
WHILE @cnt <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #columns)
BEGIN
    
    SET @column = (SELECT field_name FROM #columns WHERE ROW_NUM = @cnt)
    PRINT @column

    IF @column NOT IN ('monitor_date','emp_monitor_ident','employee_ident')
    BEGIN
        SET @query  = 
            'INSERT INTO Temp_table_2 
            SELECT 
            monitor_ident ='+ CAST(@monitor_ident AS VARCHAR) +',
            T1.monitor_date,
            T1.emp_monitor_ident,
            T1.employee_ident,
            T1.Column_name,
            SUBSTRING(CAST(T1.Column_value AS VARCHAR), 0, 1000) AS Column_value
        FROM Temp_table_1 WITH (NOLOCK)
            UNPIVOT
            ( Column_value
        FOR Column_name IN
        ( ['+ @column +']
            ) ) T1
        ORDER BY T1.monitor_date'
            EXECUTE(@query)
        END
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
    END
IF OBJECT_ID ('Temp_table_1')  IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE Temp_table_1    END
SET @countloop = @countloop + 1
END
```

Comment: Creo que hay un error terrible en tu proceso o hasta en el diseño. El hecho de que trabajes con múltiples tablas con columnas variables para luego pasarlas a una tabla EAV parece una pesadilla de diseño que solo traerá problemas.

Comment: aun asi, funciona, no es el codigo completo, solo quiero saber el problema con el While, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Insisto en que se debe de revisar el proceso completo, ya que hay varios indicadores de posibles problemas.

En vez de corregir el código que utiliza demasiados recursos y crea tablas al mayoreo, prefiero saltar unos cuantos pasos para hacer todo en una sola transacción. El código tiene bastantes comentarios para ir guiando paso a paso. Sin embargo, dejo referencias del [método alternativo de UNPIVOT](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/an-alternative-better-method-to-unpivot-sql-spackle) y del [método para concatenar valores](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/creating-a-comma-separated-list-sql-spackle). Desafortunadamente, ambos están en inglés pero el código también lo está, así que no crea que sea mayor problema.

```
DECLARE @string_var VARCHAR (100) = '198714,206029'
DECLARE @query      NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE Temp_table_2
(
    monitor_ident INT,
    monitor_date DATE,
    emp_monitor_ident INT,
    employee_ident INT,
    Column_name VARCHAR(1000),
    Column_value VARCHAR(1000)
)

--Iniciamos con la parte semifija de la consulta anteponiendo a todos UNION ALL para mantener todo como una transacción única
SELECT @query = ISNULL( @query, N'') + N'UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    monitor_ident = ' + CAST(s.VALUE AS nvarchar(10)) /*Convertimos el valor para poder concatenarlo.*/+ N',
    T1.monitor_date,
    T1.emp_monitor_ident,
    T1.employee_ident,
    U.Column_name,
    SUBSTRING(U.Column_value, 0, 1000) AS Column_value
FROM '
--Utilizamos el nombre guardado en las vistas del sistema y agregamos QUOTENAME para mayor seguridad. Quitamos el NOLOCK puesto que es una tabla temporal y no debería ser necesario.
+ QUOTENAME(o.name) + N' T1 
CROSS APPLY( VALUES' + 
--Estamos cambiando un bucle por una consulta que concatena filas usando XML PATH
--También cambiamos el UNPIVOT por el método más flexible que representa el uso de constructores de tabla y APPLY
--Usamos STUFF para quitar la primer coma
    STUFF( (SELECT ',(' + QUOTENAME(c.name, '''') + ', CAST( ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' AS varchar(1000)))' --Primero ponemos el nombre entre comillas y luego entre corchetes y además agregamos la conversión
    FROM TEMPDB.SYS.COLUMNS c 
    WHERE o.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID --Esto hace que solo traigamos las columnas de la tabla correspondiente
    AND c.name NOT IN ('monitor_date','emp_monitor_ident','employee_ident') --Evitamos columnas que no se deben convertir en filas
    ORDER BY c.name --ordenamos por nombre (aunque es innecesario)
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
+ N')  U( Column_Name, Column_Value)' + CHAR(10) --Nombramos las columnas
--Es importante notar que las vistas del sistema son de la base de datos tempdb donde se encuentran las tablas temporales
FROM  TEMPDB.SYS.OBJECTS o WITH(NOLOCK) 
JOIN  fn_pivotParametersINT(@string_var,',') s ON o.name = N'##get_info_' + CAST(s.VALUE AS nvarchar(10))
ORDER BY o.name;

--Cambiamos el primer UNION ALL por un INSERT INTO
SET @query = STUFF( @query, 1, 9, 'INSERT INTO Temp_table_2');

--Esta instrucción es solo para revisar el código que construimos
PRINT @query;

--Este procedimiento permite parametrizar consultas, pero no hace falta en este caso.
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query;

SELECT *
FROM Temp_table_2;
```